# If function with multiple conditions doesn't return proper value

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection

I recently started with Power Apps and one of the very first app I am building is a Body Mass Index (BMI) calculator. I was able to set it to automatically convert from Kg to pounds and cm to feet.

The problem I am facing now is outputting the result using `If` or `Switch` statement to show the BMI categories:

```
BMI Categories:
Underweight = <18.5
Normal weight = 18.5–24.9
Overweight = 25–29.9
Obesity = BMI of 30 or greater
```

The formula I intend to use is

```
BMI = 703* (weight/(Height^2))
```

This is the logic I used

```
Set(VarResult,If(tx1.Text/(tx2.Text^2)*703)=<18.5,"underweight")
if(VarResult>18.5,"Normal")
if(VarResult>=24.5,"Overweight")
if(VarResult>30, "Obese"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for assisting with the if statement, the error is with the calculation after solving the if statement.
The correct logic is

```
With(
    {res:Value(tx1.Text)/(Value(tx2.Text)^2)*10000},
     If(
        res>= 30, "Obese",
        res> 25 && res< 29.9, "Overweight",
        res> 18.5 && res< 24.9, "Normal",
        res<= 18.4, "Underweight"
      )
)
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

### Proper solution

> **NOTE**: I'm using names `WeightInput` and `HeightInput` for my inputs, Their type is **Text input**. If your configuration is different, you might amend your formula to get value with proper type.

> **NOTE**: To make the process clear, I'll use separate label element for each step. Then I'll be accessing the value of previous step by the name of the label.

#### Step 1: Get weight as number

The formula `WeightInput.Text` returns text value. We need to use [`Value()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-value) to convert it to number:

```
Value(WeightInput.Text)
```

I save it to the label named `WeightData`.

#### Step 2: Get squared value of height

We already know how to get number. Let's repeat the same with the addition of [`Power()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-numericals) (exponent value will be 2 in that case):

```
Power(Value(HeightInput.Text),2)
```

I save it to label named `SquaredWeight`

#### Step 3: Calculate BMI

Now we can use labels we saved and calculate BMI value:

```
703*(WeightData/SquaredWeight)
```

I save it as BMI.

#### Step 4: Return text value

Now, let's create another label which will contain the text value:

```
If(
    Value(BMI.Text) > 30,
    "Obese",
    Value(BMI.Text) >= 24.5,
    "Overweight",
    Value(BMI.Text) > 18.5,
    "Normal",
    Value(BMI.Text) < 18.5,
    "underweight"
)
```

Be careful with the order of conditions. If you do it the other way, you'll receive **Normal** for all values bigger than 18.5.

This is because in `If` function, **first condition evaluated to true stops the execution of the function**.

### Why the existing solution doesn't work

I can see few issues with the existing code. Most of them can be easily noticed if you follow the steps above, but I think it might be nice to point them out:

- No conversion from text to number
- Incorrect use of multi-condition `If`
- Mixing the number value with the descriptive value

To show what I mean by mixing the values. Here you save descriptive value to variable:

```
Set(VarResult,If(tx1.Text/(tx2.Text^2)*703)=<18.5,"underweight")
```

And later you try to compare it with number value:

```
if(VarResult>18.5,"Normal")
```

Comment: You fully broke down the select statement, but your answer does not solve my problem. After running your code, I keep getting "underweight" for correct values. Furthermore, I am working on improving my calculations. Thanks for assisting,

Comment: Are you able to isolate, which part of the solution is not working? Perhaps I made a typo while pasting code

Comment: Not really, you absolutely got it right. I think the problem is from my end. This is javascript code I am trying to shorten to power apps

 if (bmi <= 18.4) {
  measure = "Your BMI is " + bmi + " which means " + "you are Underweight";
 } else if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi <= 24.9) {
  measure = "Your BMI is " + bmi + " which means " + "You are Normal";
 } else if (bmi >= 25 && bmi <= 29.9) {
  measure = "Your BMI is " + bmi + " which means " + "You are Overweight";
 } else if (bmi >= 30) {
  measure = "Your BMI is " + bmi + " which means " + "You are Obese";
 }